# Firefox handling array/object serialization strangely?

Tags: arrays, json, firefox, object, trigger.io

Building a plugin via trigger.io, I'm seeing strange behavior in Chrome/Safari vs Firefox.

In Firefox, arrays are being turned into objects with numbers as keys, for example:

```
["getData", ["x"]]
```

Is getting turned into:

```
{"0":"getData","1":{"0":"x"}}
```

This causes all kinds of problems with serialization/deserialization, normalization across browsers, etc., and I'm not clear on why it would be happening.

This seems to be happening when passing objects from the foreground to the background via forge.message - happy to answer any questions to narrow this down!

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on here without knowing more about what you're doing.  Presumably you're passing the array through either `JSON.stringify` are `window.postMessage`, but exactly how?  Also, which Firefox version are you seeing this in?

Comment: This is Firefox 18. I'll post a step-by-step transformation of the data here later today.

Answer (score 3):

That does look strange, could you let us know what version of Firefox you are using?

In the mean time you could serialize and deserialize the array yourself using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse.

Comment: Hey Connor, thanks for the suggestion. It's an acceptable workaround to Firefox's problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727733/firefox-extension-is-sending-javascript-array-as-an-object-instead

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by an error in Firefox's serialization of array in extensions, see: [Firefox extension is sending javascript Array as an Object instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727733/firefox-extension-is-sending-javascript-array-as-an-object-instead)

As @connorhd said, the solution (until firefox fixes the issue) is to de/serialize to json when sending messages between the foreground and background. Unfortunately for us, this is a hotpath, and not terribly welcome overhead, but it seems to (more or less) solve the problem in Firefox 18.